# Firebase Crashlytics SDK update not working. Reports not showing in console

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Hello fellow programmers,

I am currently stuck with an issue and was wondering if someone or anyone would be able to help out.

We have upgraded the Firebase Crashlytics SDK to the newest version but now we are not receiving any reports.

I can see in the logs that everything is working correctly but the reports are now showing.

I have added the app level dependancies:

```
// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')

// Declare the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
// When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

In the app level repositories I have included:

```
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
```

App level plugins applied

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' // Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
```

I have also tried putting com.google.gms.google-services at the bottom of the Gradle file

For the project level Gradle file I have added repositories inside the allprojects:

```
google()
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
```

And of course for build script I have added repositories

```
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
google()
```

and the dependancies

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
```

The logs are showing the following when filtering for /firebase

```
2020-11-02 12:29:59.943 523-523/com.angrynerds.superbrains I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2020-11-02 12:29:59.994 523-523/com.angrynerds.superbrains I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Crashlytics 17.2.2
2020-11-02 12:30:00.009 523-523/com.angrynerds.superbrains I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

filtering /fa

```
2020-11-02 12:37:08.750 2128-2177/com.angrynerds.superbrains I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 33025
2020-11-02 12:37:08.750 2128-2177/com.angrynerds.superbrains I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-11-02 12:37:08.750 2128-2177/com.angrynerds.superbrains I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
  adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.angrynerds.superbrains
2020-11-02 12:37:08.750 2128-2177/com.angrynerds.superbrains D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-11-02 12:37:09.178 2128-2177/com.angrynerds.superbrains I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-11-02 12:37:09.254 2128-2177/com.angrynerds.superbrains D/FA: Connected to remote service
```

And I am forcing the crash with this code

```
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("Testing!!!");

    try {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Testing new crashlytics sdk :)");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
    }

    if (true) throw new RuntimeException("Test Crash"); // Force a crash
```

Please help us out, thanks.

Comment: Personally, for me it was working with gradle plugin 4.1 and gradle 6.5+, BUT reports were not deobfuscated at all so I downgraded

Comment: @fillobotto You will have to upgrade because crashlytics will stop working otherwise

Answer (score -2):

Which version of Android studio,gradle and build.gradle is there in your project? As per me using the latest versions of both should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Android studio 4.1 and Gradle build tools 4.1.0

Using Gradle wrapper version 6.5

Comment: I just checked it with the latest versions of android studio, gradle build tools and gradle wrapper which are given in the guide and it worked perfectly
link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Note: it will take some time for them to show up. Try it once and let me know before randomly downvoting my answer

Comment: I have not downvoted your answer. And to clarify, I have successfully implemented the new Crashlytics SDK in multiple projects already but this project just doesn't want to activate the new SDk for some reason. I have followed the guide already more than a couple of times. So I am basically asking if someone knows some kind of tips or tricks to properly debug this.

Comment: Alright, my mistake. i happened to have this issue in one of the projects too where it wouldn't work even for new gradle and crashlytics. for that I downgraded gradle, crashlytics and used from an even older project where it was perfectly working.

Comment: Yeah its no problem! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer and try to help. Its really weird that for some reason it just doesn't want to work.